# Issue with analysis services when setting up Reporting in TFS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I am having an issue getting reporting setup on my team foundation server because connecting to the Analysis Services throws the error

```
   The SQL Server and Instance you specified does not exist or cannot be reached
```

However, I know the Server name and Instance are both correct and they connect fine for both the Warehouse and Reporting Services. I have made sure that analysis services are running in the services and that the username and password are correct.

Here is a screenshot of what I am experiencing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but SSAS only works with windows authentication so try to use a AD user on your second tab

Comment: Yeah, the account that I am using is actually the admin account on the server and I have also tried using an admin account for the domain and neither have worked. I have tried just about every account possible, I have no idea why it isn't working. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog](http://discombobulator.net/blog/2011/01/28/a-connection-cannot-be-made-to-redirector/) in which this guy has the same issue as me and he said he finally solved it be running a repair on SSAS, could anyone tell me where I do a repair on Analysis Services in the SQL Server Configuration Manager?